# IMPLICIT TRANSACTIONS ON/OFF and BEGIN /COMMIT Transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I believe the default setting is for DML statements to be automatically committed (default is IMPLICIT TRANSACTIONS ON) but if I need to perform a BEGIN/COMMIT Transaction, does the IMPLICIT TRANSACTION setting automatically turn OFF within that BEGIN/COMMIT transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No default behavior is not Implicit Transactions, In Implicit Transactions each statement is wrapped in a new Transaction and then you have to explicitly commit it or rollback it.

Default behavior is Auto-Commit where each statement is wrapped in a transaction and on successful execution it is committed.

Explicit Transactions are when you explicitly Begin a transaction and explicitly commit a transaction, you do not need to turn off or on anything for this, just use `BEGIN TRANSACTION` before your SQL Statement and you would have started an explicit transaction, now you will have to explicitly `COMMIT TRANSACTION` or `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` .

1. If no `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement is executed , it will be the default Auto-Commit transaction mode
2. If you use `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement it will be an `Explicit Transaction`.
3. Lastly to make use of Implicit Transaction you will need to turn them on by using `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON;`

Comment: No , Auto-Commit begins a transaction and commits it for you, you dont have to do anything, Implicit transaction begins a transaction for you, but you have to commit it or rollback it.